# IE8 Some html is missing

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have an issue in IE8. Some part of my html and some script tags are not displaying on page and not in firebug. I do not know why this issue occur but same page is displaying perfect in IE9. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a tag opening/closing issue, I suggest you try and validate your html on http://validator.w3.org/